# Issue with importing SCVI package into an jupyter environment [partially initialized module 'jax' has no attribute 'version']

Tags: python, jupyter, conda, jax, rna-seq

I am analyzing single cell RNA-seq data in jupyter utilizing python3. In order to delineate differential expression between cells/samples/etc. scanpy and SCVI is needed to perform the task i need. I am able to install SCVI and I installed scvi-tools into jupyter:

[!pip3 install SCVI]
[!pip install "scvi-tools[tutorials]"]

-This was successful.

Proceeded to import SCVI and this error occured

[ import scvi ]

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[264], line 1
----> 1 import scvi

File ~/opt/miniconda3/envs/env_x86/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scvi/__init__.py:10
      7 from ._settings import settings
      9 # this import needs to come after prior imports to prevent circular import
---> 10 from . import data, model, external, utils
     12 # https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/pull/2366#issuecomment-652418094
     13 # https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/144#issuecomment-623927302
     14 try:

File ~/opt/miniconda3/envs/env_x86/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scvi/data/__init__.py:3
      1 from anndata import read_csv, read_h5ad, read_loom, read_text
----> 3 from ._datasets import (
      4     annotation_simulation,
      5     brainlarge_dataset,
      6     breast_cancer_dataset,
      7     cortex,
      8     dataset_10x,
      9     frontalcortex_dropseq,
     10     heart_cell_atlas_subsampled,
     11     mouse_ob_dataset,
     12     pbmc_dataset,
     13     pbmc_seurat_v4_cite_seq,
     14     pbmcs_10x_cite_seq,
     15     prefrontalcortex_starmap,
     16     purified_pbmc_dataset,
     17     retina,
     18     seqfish,
     19     seqfishplus,
     20     smfish,
     21     spleen_lymph_cite_seq,
     22     synthetic_iid,
     23 )
     24 from ._manager import AnnDataManager, AnnDataManagerValidationCheck
     25 from ._preprocessing import (
     26     organize_cite_seq_10x,
     27     organize_multiome_anndatas,
     28     poisson_gene_selection,
     29 )

File ~/opt/miniconda3/envs/env_x86/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scvi/data/_datasets.py:5
      1 from typing import List, Optional
      3 import anndata
----> 5 from ._built_in_data._brain_large import _load_brainlarge_dataset
      6 from ._built_in_data._cite_seq import (
      7     _load_pbmc_seurat_v4_cite_seq,
      8     _load_pbmcs_10x_cite_seq,
      9     _load_spleen_lymph_cite_seq,
     10 )
     11 from ._built_in_data._cortex import _load_cortex

File ~/opt/miniconda3/envs/env_x86/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scvi/data/_built_in_data/_brain_large.py:9
      6 import numpy as np
      7 import scipy.sparse as sp_sparse
----> 9 from scvi.data._download import _download
     11 logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
     14 def _load_brainlarge_dataset(
     15     save_path: str = "data/",
     16     sample_size_gene_var: int = 10000,
   (...)
     19     loading_batch_size: int = 100000,
     20 ) -> anndata.AnnData:

File ~/opt/miniconda3/envs/env_x86/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scvi/data/_download.py:8
      4 from typing import Optional
      6 import numpy as np
----> 8 from scvi.utils import track
     10 logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
     13 def _download(url: Optional[str], save_path: str, filename: str):

File ~/opt/miniconda3/envs/env_x86/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scvi/utils/__init__.py:4
      2 from ._decorators import unsupported_in_latent_mode
      3 from ._docstrings import setup_anndata_dsp
----> 4 from ._jax import device_selecting_PRNGKey
      5 from ._track import track
      7 __all__ = [
      8     "track",
      9     "setup_anndata_dsp",
   (...)
     12     "unsupported_in_latent_mode",
     13 ]

File ~/opt/miniconda3/envs/env_x86/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scvi/utils/_jax.py:3
      1 from typing import Callable
----> 3 import jax
      4 from jax import random
      7 def device_selecting_PRNGKey(use_cpu: bool = True) -> Callable:

File ~/opt/miniconda3/envs/env_x86/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jax/__init__.py:35
     30 del _cloud_tpu_init
     32 # Confusingly there are two things named "config": the module and the class.
     33 # We want the exported object to be the class, so we first import the module
     34 # to make sure a later import doesn't overwrite the class.
---> 35 from jax import config as _config_module
     36 del _config_module
     38 from jax._src.basearray import Array as Array

File ~/opt/miniconda3/envs/env_x86/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jax/config.py:17
      1 # Copyright 2018 The JAX Authors.
      2 #
      3 # Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
   (...)
     14 
     15 # TODO(phawkins): fix users of this alias and delete this file.
---> 17 from jax._src.config import config

File ~/opt/miniconda3/envs/env_x86/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jax/_src/config.py:28
     25 import warnings
     26 from typing import Any, List, Callable, Hashable, NamedTuple, Iterator, Optional
---> 28 from jax._src import lib
     29 from jax._src.lib import jax_jit
     30 from jax._src.lib import transfer_guard_lib

File ~/opt/miniconda3/envs/env_x86/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jax/_src/lib/__init__.py:75
     71   return _jaxlib_version
     73 version_str = jaxlib.version.__version__
     74 version = check_jaxlib_version(
---> 75   jax_version=jax.version.__version__,
     76   jaxlib_version=jaxlib.version.__version__,
     77   minimum_jaxlib_version=jax.version._minimum_jaxlib_version)
     81 # Before importing any C compiled modules from jaxlib, first import the CPU
     82 # feature guard module to verify that jaxlib was compiled in a way that only
     83 # uses instructions that are present on this machine.
     84 import jaxlib.cpu_feature_guard as cpu_feature_guard

AttributeError: partially initialized module 'jax' has no attribute 'version' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

I am using a mac - M1 - 13.0.1
Python --version 3.9.15

What am I missing?

I have tried installing SCVI using brew forge in conda environment

[ brew install --cask mambaforge ]

This was in my zsh terminal.

I'm assuming there is an issue with my GPU prerequisites

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Not reproducible. Please try defining an environment with a YAML, then if you still have issues, share the YAML with us. Please avoid *ad hoc* commands (e.g., `pip install` in an IPython cell).

Comment: Hello Merv, thank you for your comment. I switched environments in conda to env_86 and successfully imported scvi but however now I have another error in regards to my CPU not supporting jaxlib. I need to submit another question

Comment: `jaxlib` compiled for **x86_64** may not be compatible with an **arm64** chip, which has to run **x86_64** code in emulation.

Comment: Hello @SamuelS, if you are getting error related to the CPU, you can try the following command: `pip uninstall jax jaxlib` then try the following command: `conda install -c conda-forge jaxlib` and then 
`conda install -c conda-forge jax`